# How can I create a timer in C?

Tags: c, timer

I want to create a timer that counts seconds and display them, but in parallel I want to do other actions. Can someone explain me how can I do that or if this is possible (in Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is one way to handle your desired actions.

in main thread, 
-fork a child process. passing
    1) a desired time interval 
    2) a callback function ptr
    3) indication of oneShot or repeating timer
    into the child process,

in the child process:
-begin loop
    -sleep the passed-in-time-interval
    -execute the call back function 
    -if non repeating timer
    -then
        -exit child process
    -endif
-end loop

in main thread, in the call back function:
-get current time
-display the current time to user
-return

in main thread, when ready to exit, kill child thread
```